# Microsoft Asynchronous Conversation Transcription problem: SLF4J problem + Connection Issue Error 11001

Tags: java, azure, speech-recognition

I tried to run the sample code from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-async-conversation-transcription

implementing helper class from:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/java/jre/console/src/com/microsoft/cognitiveservices/speech/samples/console/WavStream.java

with some slight modifications so that it can read in wav files not limited to 16kHz 16bit single channel, and when I run it, this comes up:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Conversation transcriber canceled:SessionId:b2496d2c13424b3ba3138f2c8ce0893f ResultId:258796dbc69d491786f3ccdd8ec708d6 CancellationReason:Error CancellationErrorCode:ConnectionFailure Error details:<Connection failed (no connection to the remote host). Internal error: 1. Error details: 11001. Please check network connection, firewall setting, and the region name used to create speech factory. SessionId: b2496d2c13424b3ba3138f2c8ce0893f
Conversation transcriber stopped:SessionId: b2496d2c13424b3ba3138f2c8ce0893f.
```

I'm pretty sure that the API key and the region setup are correct and running and the Internet configuration isn't having any problem.

Here are the codes:

Main.java:

```
package speechsdk.quickstart;

import com.azure.core.util.polling.PollerFlux;
import com.azure.core.util.polling.SyncPoller;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.*;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.*;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.remoteconversation.RemoteConversationTranscriptionClient;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.remoteconversation.RemoteConversationTranscriptionOperation;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.remoteconversation.RemoteConversationTranscriptionResult;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.transcription.Conversation;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.transcription.ConversationTranscriber;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.transcription.ConversationTranscriptionResult;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

/**
 * Quickstart: recognize speech using the Speech SDK for Java.
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args Arguments are ignored in this sample.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Create the speech config object
            SpeechConfig speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("APIKEY", "SERVICEREGION");

            speechConfig.setProperty("ConversationTranscriptionInRoomAndOnline", "true");

// Set the property for asynchronous transcription
            speechConfig.setServiceProperty("transcriptionMode", "Async", ServicePropertyChannel.UriQueryParameter);

// Set the property for real-time plus asynchronous transcription
//speechConfig.setServiceProperty("transcriptionMode", "RealTimeAndAsync", ServicePropertyChannel.UriQueryParameter);

// pick a conversation Id that is a GUID.
            String conversationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

// Create a Conversation
            Conversation conversation = new Conversation(speechConfig, conversationId);

// Create an audio stream from a wav file or from the default microphone if you want to stream live audio from the supported devices
// Replace with your own audio file name and Helper class which implements AudioConfig using PullAudioInputStreamCallback
            WavStream wavStream =  new WavStream(new FileInputStream("sample.wav"));
            PullAudioInputStreamCallback wavfilePullStreamCallback = wavStream;

// Create an audio stream format assuming the file used above is 16Khz, 16 bits and 8 channel pcm wav file
            //AudioStreamFormat audioStreamFormat = AudioStreamFormat.getWaveFormatPCM((long)16000, (short)16,(short)8);
            AudioStreamFormat audioStreamFormat = AudioStreamFormat.getWaveFormatPCM(wavStream.getSamplespersecond(), (short) wavStream.getBitspersample(), (short) wavStream.getChannel());
// Create an input stream
            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioInputStream.createPullStream(wavfilePullStreamCallback, audioStreamFormat);

// Create a conversation transcriber
            ConversationTranscriber transcriber = new ConversationTranscriber(AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(audioStream));

// join a conversation
            transcriber.joinConversationAsync(conversation);

// Add the event listener for the realtime events
            transcriber.transcribed.addEventListener((o, e) -> {
                System.out.println("Conversation transcriber Recognized:" + e.toString());
            });

            transcriber.canceled.addEventListener((o, e) -> {
                System.out.println("Conversation transcriber canceled:" + e.toString());
                try {
                    transcriber.stopTranscribingAsync().get();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            transcriber.sessionStopped.addEventListener((o, e) -> {
                System.out.println("Conversation transcriber stopped:" + e.toString());

                try {
                    transcriber.stopTranscribingAsync().get();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

// start the transcription.
            Future<?> future = transcriber.startTranscribingAsync();


// Create a remote Conversation Transcription client
            RemoteConversationTranscriptionClient client = new RemoteConversationTranscriptionClient(speechConfig);

// Get the PollerFlux for the remote operation
            PollerFlux<RemoteConversationTranscriptionOperation, RemoteConversationTranscriptionResult> remoteTranscriptionOperation = client.getTranscriptionOperation(conversationId);

// Subscribe to PollerFlux to get the remote operation status
            remoteTranscriptionOperation.subscribe(
                    pollResponse -> {
                        System.out.println("Poll response status : " + pollResponse.getStatus());
                        System.out.println("Poll response status : " + pollResponse.getValue().getServiceStatus());
                    }
            );

// Obtain the blocking operation using getSyncPoller
            SyncPoller<RemoteConversationTranscriptionOperation, RemoteConversationTranscriptionResult> blockingOperation =  remoteTranscriptionOperation.getSyncPoller();

// Wait for the operation to finish
            blockingOperation.waitForCompletion();

// Get the final result response
            RemoteConversationTranscriptionResult resultResponse = blockingOperation.getFinalResult();

// Print the result
            if(resultResponse != null) {
                if(resultResponse.getConversationTranscriptionResults() != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < resultResponse.getConversationTranscriptionResults().size(); i++) {
                        ConversationTranscriptionResult result = resultResponse.getConversationTranscriptionResults().get(i);
                        System.out.println(result.getProperties().getProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_JsonResult.name()));
                        System.out.println(result.getProperties().getProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_JsonResult));
                        System.out.println(result.getOffset());
                        System.out.println(result.getDuration());
                        System.out.println(result.getUserId());
                        System.out.println(result.getReason());
                        System.out.println(result.getResultId());
                        System.out.println(result.getText());
                        System.out.println(result.toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Operation finished");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //System.out.println("Unexpected exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();

            assert(false);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Helper.java:

```
package speechsdk.quickstart;

import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.PullAudioInputStreamCallback;
import com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.AudioConfig;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.slf4j.*;

class   WavStream extends PullAudioInputStreamCallback {
    private final InputStream stream;
    private long samplespersecond;
    private int bitspersample;
    private int channel;

    public long getSamplespersecond()
    {
        return samplespersecond;
    }

    public int getBitspersample()
    {
        return bitspersample;
    }

    public int getChannel()
    {
        return channel;
    }

    public WavStream(InputStream wavStream) {
        try {
            this.stream = parseWavHeader(wavStream);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] dataBuffer) {
        long ret = 0;

        try {
            ret = this.stream.read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.length);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Read " + ex);
        }

        return (int)Math.max(0, ret);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        try {
            this.stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignored
        }
    }
    // endregion

    // region Wav File helper functions
    private int ReadInt32(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            n |= inputStream.read() << (i * 8);
        }
        return n;
    }

    private long ReadUInt32(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        long n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            n |= inputStream.read() << (i * 8);
        }
        return n;
    }

    private int ReadUInt16(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            n |= inputStream.read() << (i * 8);
        }
        return n;
    }

    public InputStream parseWavHeader(InputStream reader) throws IOException {
        // Note: assumption about order of chunks
        // Tag "RIFF"
        byte data[] = new byte[4];
        int numRead = reader.read(data, 0, 4);
        ThrowIfFalse((numRead == 4) && (data[0] == 'R') && (data[1] == 'I') && (data[2] == 'F') && (data[3] == 'F'), "RIFF");

        // Chunk size
        /* int fileLength = */ReadInt32(reader);

        // Subchunk, Wave Header
        // Subchunk, Format
        // Tag: "WAVE"
        numRead = reader.read(data, 0, 4);
        ThrowIfFalse((numRead == 4) && (data[0] == 'W') && (data[1] == 'A') && (data[2] == 'V') && (data[3] == 'E'), "WAVE");

        // Tag: "fmt"
        numRead = reader.read(data, 0, 4);
        ThrowIfFalse((numRead == 4) && (data[0] == 'f') && (data[1] == 'm') && (data[2] == 't') && (data[3] == ' '), "fmt ");

        // chunk format size
        long formatSize = ReadInt32(reader);
        ThrowIfFalse(formatSize >= 16, "formatSize");

        int formatTag = ReadUInt16(reader);
        int channels = ReadUInt16(reader);
        int samplesPerSec = (int) ReadUInt32(reader);
        int avgBytesPerSec = (int) ReadUInt32(reader);
        int blockAlign = ReadUInt16(reader);
        int bitsPerSample = ReadUInt16(reader);
        ThrowIfFalse(formatTag == 1, "PCM"); // PCM
        //ThrowIfFalse(channels == 1, "single channel");
        channel = channels;
        //ThrowIfFalse(samplesPerSec == 16000, "samples per second");
        samplespersecond = samplesPerSec;
        //ThrowIfFalse(bitsPerSample == 16, "bits per sample");
        bitspersample = bitsPerSample;

        // Until now we have read 16 bytes in format, the rest is cbSize and is ignored
        // for now.
        if (formatSize > 16) {
            numRead = reader.read(new byte[(int) (formatSize - 16)]);
            ThrowIfFalse(numRead == (int)(formatSize - 16), "could not skip extended format");
        }

        // Second Chunk, data
        // tag: data.
        numRead = reader.read(data, 0, 4);
        //for (byte i : data) System.out.print((char) i);
        //System.out.println();
        //ThrowIfFalse((numRead == 4) && (data[0] == 'd') && (data[1] == 'a') && (data[2] == 't') && (data[3] == 'a'), "data");

        // data chunk size
        // Note: assumption is that only a single data chunk
        /* int dataLength = */ReadInt32(reader);
        numRead = reader.read(data, 0, 4);
        while (!((numRead == 4) && (data[0] == 'd') && (data[1] == 'a') && (data[2] == 't') && (data[3] == 'a')))
        {
            numRead = reader.read(data, 0, 4);
            //for (byte i : data) System.out.print((char) i);
            //System.out.println();
            ReadInt32(reader);
        }
        //for (byte i : data) System.out.println((char) i);
        return reader;
    }

    private static void ThrowIfFalse(Boolean condition, String message) {
        if (!condition) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
        }
    }
    // endregion
}
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I have exactly the same problem (although in C#)

Answer (score 0):

Using [azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-logging), if you can please configure the following and provide us the log.

```
config.setProperty(PropertyId.Speech_LogFilename, "LogfilePathAndName");
```

By the way, what is the region you are using to do the transcription?

Comment: I configured it, but there was no log file generated. I suppose it's due to the connection failure or the SLF4J failure the session failed from the very start. I'm using the region of uksouth. Could it be that the Microsoft Speech SDK only takes in 16000Hz, 16-bit mono track sound files so that it will outright reject any other files that are not this configuration?

Comment: For conversation transcription, the input wave file should be 8 channel, 16 bits and 16 Khz wave file. Try putting a sleep after 
// start the transcription.
            Future<?> future = transcriber.startTranscribingAsync();

Answer (score 0):

For conversation transcription, the input wave file should be 8 channel, 16 bits and 16 Khz wave file. Try putting a sleep after the following code till you get the session stopped called.

```java
// start the transcription.
            Future<?> future = transcriber.startTranscribingAsync();
```

Also if possible change the following code to

```java
PollerFlux<RemoteConversationTranscriptionOperation, RemoteConversationTranscriptionResult> remoteTranscriptionOperation = client.getTranscriptionOperation(conversationId,5);
```

Do let us know if it works.